# Is it possible to read crawldb using java code?

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

I am using Nutch to crawl a website, and i want to collect all 404 urls in the crawling process. Then i looked up Nutch wiki and i found that using nutch command 'readdb' can produce something like:

> http://xxx.yy.com/  Version: 7
>
> Status: 1 (db_unfetched)
>
> Fetch time: Sun Dec 08 21:42:34 CST 2013
>
> Modified time: Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970
>
> Retries since fetch: 0
>
> Retry interval: 2592000 seconds (30 days)
>
> Score: 1
>
> Signature: null
>
> Metadata:

And all 404 urls has the status 3.

I think that these imformathion are all from crawldb. So is there any way to read crawldb using java code? I also learned that nutch stores data on HDFS, so do i need using hadoop tools to read them? Or is there any better way to achieve my requirement?

P.s. My Nutch version is 1.13, and my running environment is Ubuntu16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nutch is written in Java, so yes is possible, actually the `readdb` command is doing that exactly, the logic of the `readdb` command is in the `org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDbReader` class. You can take a look there to implement your own command.

About the Hadoop part of your question, Nutch is built on top of Hadoop, meaning we use the Hadoop libraries, even if you're running Nutch locally, so you should use the Hadoop libraries (especially if you want to run your crawler in a cluster at some point).

If you just want to get a list of all the 404, you could use the `-status` option of the `readdb` command.

You could also take a look at [NUTCH-2229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2229) which added support for using JEXL expressions on the `readdb` command so you could just get the list of 404 URLs from the CrawlDB without the need to write your own code.